# Ember.js Computed Properties (Overwriting get and set)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on an Ember.js application and I'm using ember-cli 2.7.
I'm trying to overwrite the properties for get and set, but when I do, I get an unexpected token error.

Here is the code of my controller file:

```
  import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  isDisabled: true,

  emailAddress: '',

  actualEmailAddress: Ember.computed('emailAddress', function(){
    get(key){
      return `getting email...${this.get('emailAddress')}`;
    }
  }),

  emailAddressChanged: Ember.observer('emailAddress', function(){
    console.log('observer is called: ', this.get('emailAddress'));
  })
});
```

This seems like a simple solution, but I do not find the bug and it's killing me. Please help me and thank you.

Comment: @ykaragol it was not a syntax error. I removed the "function" key word, but it still resulted in the same runtime error.

EDIT: jk, it was the error, but I get another one lol

Comment: what is the behaviour? what is the current error/problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntax error. `function` shouldn't be at there. Computed property definition should be like this:

```
actualEmailAddress: Ember.computed('emailAddress', {
    get(key){
      return `getting email...${this.get('emailAddress')}`;
   },
   set(key, value){
       //...
   }
}),
```

If you only have a `get` operation at a computed property, then you can write it as following:

```
actualEmailAddress: Ember.computed('emailAddress', function(){
    return `getting email...${this.get('emailAddress')}`;
}),
```